# two way data binding with watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Why is $scope.watch not working with 'model'?
http://jsfiddle.net/lesouthern/8PUtP/5/

```
.directive('testDirective',function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : {
            model : '=ngModel'
        },
        link : function($scope,$element,$attrs) {
            $scope.$watch('model',function(x) {
                console.log('this is model: ' + x);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In this case the "=" should be "@"   [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcsYE/)

Comment: [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14063373/2013981) sums it up.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419629/angularjs-two-way-data-binding-fails-if-element-has-ngmodel-and-a-custom-direct). Here is your corrected code :

```js
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.$watch($attrs.ngModel, function(x) {
            console.log('this is model: ' + x);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. The issue with this solution is that I need to restrict scope in this directive. How do I watch the value of this input, and have two way data binding with this scope variable?

Comment: @koolunix IMHO, you should accept this answer because you used the exact same solution in your answer.

Comment: the complete question had the requirement of limiting the scope of the directive. what is shown above does not answer this

Comment: Notice that your solution doesn't restrict the scope neither. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14116498/2057033) (and the related comments) will give you more details about what to do.

Comment: @Blackhole you are right. Thanks for your input. Here is an updated answer based on that link: http://jsfiddle.net/lesouthern/WN6aC/2/