# How to set angular controller object property value from directive in child scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have have a directive inside an ng-repeater that should set a scope property.
Please see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/paos/CSbRB/

The problem is that the scope property is given as an attribute value like this:

```
<button ng-update1="inputdata.title">click me</button>
```

The directive is supposed to set the scope property inputdata.title to some string. This does not work:

```
app.directive('ngUpdate1', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                scope[ attrs.ngUpdate1 ] = "Button 1";
            });
        });
    };
});
```

However, assigning directly works:

```
scope["inputdata"]["title"] = "Button 1";
```

Can you please tell me how I can set a scope property with . notation in its name from a directive?

PS: The reason the fiddle is using a repeater is because it makes the directives be in child scopes. When they are in a child scope, you can't write to scope properties that are primitives. That's why I need an object property with "." in the name. See the long explanation here: [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482)

Thank you

Comment: An inelegant solution would be to use the string form of `$apply`, e.g.: `scope.$apply( attrs.ngUpdate1 + '=' + '"Button 1"' );`.

Comment: @Josh, in case you didn't see my answer, the elegant solution is to use `$parse`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse) will solve your problem.

```
<button ng-update1="inputdata.title">
```

```js
app.directive('ngUpdate1', function($parse) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.ngUpdate1);
        console.log(model(scope));  // logs "test"
        element.bind('click', function() {
           model.assign(scope, "Button 1");
           scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/J4ccY/)

Whenever a directive does not use an isolate scope and you specify a scope property using an attribute, and you want to modify the value, use `$parse`.

If you don't need to modify the value, you can use `$eval` instead:

```
console.log(scope.$eval(attrs.ngUpdate1));
```

Comment: Can you do the same thing using ng-model as the html attribute instead of a custom one assuming your html element is a directive and you've got the code you presented here in a link: function?

Comment: @sonicblis, I suggest posting a new question with a fiddle, since you are asking about a very different scenario.  The answer will also depend on the type of scope the directive is using.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896732/ngmodel-and-component-with-isolated-scope

Comment: @MarkRajcok, I appreciate it, but I figured it out.  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sonicblis/99r7v/) shows what I was asking about.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what overall objective is but one way is to create 2 attributes, one for the target object and the other for the property of that object:

```
<button ng-update1  obj="inputdata" prop="title">
```

```
app.directive('ngUpdate1', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {                
                scope[ attrs.obj ][attrs.prop] = "Button 1";               

            });
        });
    };
});
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/CSbRB/9/

Alternatively using existing format you could `split()` value of your current `ng-update1` attribute and use result array for object and property in notation

```
 element.bind('click', function() {
           var target=attrs.ngUpdate1.split('.');
            scope.$apply(function() {                
                scope[ target[0] ][target[1]] = "Button 1";               

            });
        });
```

DEMO with both approaches: http://jsfiddle.net/CSbRB/10/

One more approach where you create an isolated scope in directive and can pass in the reference to `inputdata` object and pull property name from attribute(same markup as second version):

```
app.directive('ngUpdate3', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
           targetObject: '=obj'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {  
               scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.targetObject[attrs.prop]='Button 3';

                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CSbRB/11/

Comment: Instead of two attributes or `split()`, use `$parse` instead (see my answer).  Also, with an isolate scope, you can bind to the object property directly if you want/need to: `<button ng-update3 model="inputdata.title" ...>`, then in the directive: `scope: { model: '=' }`.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/3nb8D/)

Comment: @MarkRajcok thanks.. was trying to bind to property in isolated scope earlier and not sure why it wasn't working..  docs for $parse are terrible...your comments help. Seems like there should more intuitive approaches than needing to use `$parse` then `assign`

Comment: I had problems binding to a property in an isolated scope in your fiddle too.  I think the issue is the older version of Angular (1.0.0) in your fiddle.

Comment: 3 different approaches make my mind open outside the box. Thank you very much for useful explanations.