# Setup bi-directional binding from an object defined in an html attribute in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have implemented a remote validation directive which queries a specified JSON API endpoint once an input is blurred. It expects the response `{ valid: true|false }`.

I now have to extend it to allow for it to send a request involving multiple values from the parent scope.

My tag definition looks as follows:

```
<input remote-validate endpoint="/api/action/:value" ng-model="MyInput" />
```

where :value is substituted with a urlencoded value of $scope.MyInput.
This is working well.

What I require is given an endpoint like this `/api/action/:value/:person/:thing`, the :person and :thing substitutions are bound to the parent scope values.
My initial thought is to have a `bindings` attribute which maps the parent scope to the endpoint.

```
<input remote-validate endpoint="/api/action/:value/:person/:thing" bindings="{person: 'firstName', thing: 'thingName'}" ng-model="MyInput" />
(...)
<input ng-model="firstName" />    <input ng-model="thingName" />
```

given `var bindings = scope.$eval(attrs.bindings);` is there any way to loop through the `bindings` object and create a two way binding to the parent scope?

EDIT: A workaround may be to do this:

```
<input validate-remotely 
    endpoint="api/action/:value/:param1/:param2" 
    param1="person" 
    param2="thing" />
```

which obviously means I can only use the number of parameters I specify in the scope definition. Which is a good work around for me here. Would be nice to know if there was a way to create these bindings dynamically at compile/link time.

I can provide a fiddle but I don't have the time right now, so I'm hoping that someone will have a good idea if/how this is possible.

Comment: why dont you just use bidiretional binding using '=' available with directives

Comment: Because I want to map arbitrarily named :tags in the url endpoint string to the parent scope. I know I could do something like this: <input validate-remotely endpoint=":a/:b/:c" a="parentModel" ... />, but then I would have to define 'a' in my directive scope. `scope: {a:'='}` - which would mean my directive isn't generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it in a not so ideal way.

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E8xCdP3zjeXBIitOtwSF?p=preview), which has a copy of the directive I use live and works well in my app but doesn't work in Plunker (I expect the randomly chosen `plunker` api endpoint to be called and fail, but it is not called due to some strange errors I don't care to debug).

The problem I had with the proposed workaround in the EDIT of this question is that it seems you cannot use `scope` and `require` in the same `directive`. **I would love it if someone could elaborate on if this is the case and why.**

### The Workaround

I used a `params` attribute to specify additional data in object notation to be extended to go to the resource request. I used the *handlebars* syntax in the params attribute to dynamically change the object notation string.

```
<input ng-model="value2" ... />
<input validate-remotely 
       endpoint="/api/:value/?thing=:anotherValue" 
       params="{ anotherValue: '{{ value2 }}' }"  ... />
```

Not so great :/ but it works.

Then on `blur` of the validated input, I re-$eval the object string (app.js:40 in the plunker) and extend the resources data to include this object, which using `ngResources` colon (:) notation, replaces the URL.

The validation has 3 states:

`remoteValidityPending`: field validation fails because it is still being checked - good for showing a spinner.

`remoteValidityUnchecked`: The field has changed since it has been checked but has not yet blurred - ensures that any `ng-disable="form.$invalid"' submit buttons stay disabled until we know that the backend has returned a response.

`remoteValidity`: If this passes, the fields endpoint has been called and '{valid: true}' has been returned from the server.

I'm almost certain there are better/different ways to solve this, and I'll be happy to change the answer if someone improves this directive. I hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

As I learned yesterday, you can use `$parse` on your 'binding' attributes.  [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15725402/215945).  This is a good way to `$watch` an attribute for changes that come from parent or children

Example:

```
<div parse-test bindings="{person: 'firstName', thing: 'thingName'}"></div>

// in your directive link function:
scope.bindings = $parse(attrs.bindings)(scope);
  scope.$watch('bindings', function(val){
    for (i in scope.bindings){
      scope[i] = scope.bindings[i];
    }  
  }, true);
```

Experiment with [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YhaUL3sEBCckGGlVJoNa?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me think of a solution :)