# Angular - Passing variables to the directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to pass an object to the directive scope:

**JS:**

```
app.directive('validatePrice', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, el, attrs){
            console.log(attrs.validatePrice);
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

`<button validate-price="{priceValid: {'disabled': 'disabled'}}">Checkout</button>`

where `priceValid` is a boolean from the controller scope and `{'disabled': 'disabled'}` is  just a plain object. I expect my `attrs.validatePrice` to return eg:

```
{
    true: {'disabled': 'disabled'}
}
```

Yet it returns string. How do I do that? :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think what you want is possible.  `priceValid` will be interpreted as an object key by JavaScript – it will not be interpreted as `true`.

Anyway, [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse) or [$eval](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$eval) is what you need to use to pass an object to a directive (if you are not using an isolated scope):

```
<button validate-price="{priceValid: {'disabled': 'disabled'}}">Checkout</button>
```

```
app.directive('validatePrice', function($parse) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, el, attrs){
            var model = $parse(attrs.validatePrice);
            console.log(model(scope));
            console.log(scope.$eval(attrs.validatePrice));
        }
    };
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/NWENH/)

Use $parse if you need to alter the object. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15725402/215945 for an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<validate-price-dir validate-price="{priceValid: {'disabled': 'disabled'}}">Checkout</validate-price-dir>    

app.directive('validatePriceDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { validatePrice: '=validatePrice' },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs){
            console.log(scope.validatePrice);
        }
   };
});
```

Comment: Not only it returns string, but it also throws `Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`.

Comment: by default directives are restricted to type A (attributes). you have an attribute with the same name as the directive: infinite loop