# Custom validation directive with isolated scope in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Take a look at the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AaQtz/21/. As you can see, the custom validation runs and when the value is considered valid it is updated in the model.

However, when I add `scope: {},` to the directive, the model is no longer receiving updates when the value is valid. Why is this? This behaviour makes it very hard to build a directive that validates a field depending on other fields (fields I would like to pass using the scope, such as `scope: { somefield: '=' },`). JSFiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JYUmT/1/.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-model and isolate scopes do not mix: [Can I use ng-model with isolated scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896732/ngmodel-and-component-with-isolated-scope)

Use $eval or $parse to pass/examine attributes in a directive that doesn't use an isolate scope: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15725402/215945

Comment: Thanks for the notes on `$eval` and `$parse`, useful. I would be interested in an explanation to why "ng-model and isolate scopes do not mix", but I'll accept this as I understand that might be an implementation detail.