# do not see model value if use directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            field: '='
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, contr) {
            contr.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                console.log(scope.mymodel);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and I have a form that uses the directive

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="mymodel" mydirective field="123" />
  <div>{{mymodel}}</div>
</form>
```

the model of the `input` element is set to `mymodel`. Under the `input` I would like to display the value of this model.

The problem is that the value `{{mymodel}}` is not rendered. And it seems that `mymodel` in the current `$scope` never changes as I type in the `input` field.

I thought that this is because the directive creates another scope, but `console.log(scope.mymodel)` inside the `link` function outputs `undefined` as well.

Without `mydirective` in `input` I can see the model's value under the field with no problems.

Could someone please explain where the model is kept? Which scope is it in?

the live code:

http://jsfiddle.net/E8QXz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. As Chandermani wrote, you're introducing a new scope with `scope: { field: '=' },` on the input. Thus you'll need to reference `mymodel` as `ng-model="$parent.mymodel"` or angular will look on the wrong scope.

   ```
   <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.mymodel" mydirective field="123" />
   ```
2. [`$parsers`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#%24parsers) should return a value, otherwise the parser chain is broken.

   ```
   ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
     console.log(value);
     return value; // <- add this
   });
   ```

---

Fixed code (excuse the restructuring ;)):

```
(function (app, ng) {
  app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function submit() {
      console.log('submit');
    };
  }]);

  app.directive('mydirective', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: { field: '=' },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
          console.log(value);
          return value; // <- add this
        });
      }
    };
  });
}(angular.module('myapp', []), angular));
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/uzixey/1/

Answer (score 1):

Since you have created a scope object in directive definition, it creates an isolated scope which does not inherit from the parent scope. ng-model and isolated scope do not work well. [See this from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699495/custom-validation-directive-with-isolated-scope-in-angularjs/17701734#17701734)