# AngularJS : 2-way binding broke when creating new child scope in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using custom angular form validation to validate fields based off the field having a value AND the selected value of a drop down. I use the same section of code (and therefore the same directive) twice on the page. So I could do this re-use, I tried sending in an argument to the directive. This is all working fine. However when the child scope is created it breaks my 2-way binding back to `fruit.cost`.

[Here is an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmontgomery/8ryEL/).

What am I doing wrong? I want all the validation to work the same but also preserve the 2-way binding. Here is a copy of my fiddle code:

**JS**

```
function MainCtrl($scope){
  $scope.localFruits = [
      {name: 'banana'},
      {name: 'orange'},
      {name: 'grape'}
  ];
  $scope.fruits = [
      {name: 'banana'},
      {name: 'orange'},
      {name: 'grape'}
  ];
  $scope.costRequired = [
      'local',
      'overseas'
  ];
  $scope.selectedCostRequired = '';
}

angular.module('test', []).directive('customRequired', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
          requiredWhenKey: '=',
          cost: '=' // I think the problem is here?? Can't figure out how to pass the property I want to bind to
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
          //console.log(scope);
          function isValid(value) {
              if (scope.$parent.selectedCostRequired === scope.requiredWhenKey) {
                  return !!value;
              }
              return true;
          }

          ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
              var valid = isValid(value);
              scope.$parent.subForm.cost.$setValidity('customRequired', valid);
              return valid ? value : undefined;
          });

          ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
              scope.$parent.subForm.cost.$setValidity('customRequired', isValid(value));
              return value;
          });

          scope.$watch('$parent.$parent.selectedCostRequired', function() {
              scope.$parent.subForm.cost.$setValidity('customRequired', isValid(ctrl.$modelValue));
          });
      }
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<form name="form">
    Which grouping is required? <select name="costRequired" ng-model="selectedCostRequired" ng-options="t for t in costRequired"></select>
    <h2>Local</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="fruit in localFruits" ng-form="subForm">
        {{fruit.name}}: <input name="cost" ng-model="fruit.cost" required-when-key="'local'" custom-required/> bound value is: [{{fruit.cost}}]
        <span class="error" ng-show="subForm.cost.$error.customRequired">Required</span>
    </div>
    <h2>Overseas</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-form="subForm">
        {{fruit.name}}: <input name="cost" ng-model="fruit.cost" required-when-key="'overseas'" custom-required/> bound value is: [{{fruit.cost}}]
        <span class="error" ng-show="subForm.cost.$error.customRequired">Required</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="form.$invalid" class="error">some form error(s) still exist</div>
    <div ng-show="!form.$invalid" class="okay">form looks good!</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: The fiddle seems to be working, what else do you want it to do?

Comment: @sh0ber the problem is the two-way binding is not keeping the original scope up to date. I can see how my question was confusing... I've updated the fiddle to be a little more clear

Comment: i'm not exactly sure what's going on in your code, but have you tried using '=attributeToBindTo' instead of '=' in your directive scope? If not, see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive, scroll to `scope` under `Directive Definition Object`

Comment: @sh0ber I tried `cost: '=ngModel'`, `cost: '=cost'` and `cost: '='` to no avail. It's not clear to me what I should try to pass in since my input has `ng-model="fruit.cost"`. I assume `cost`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ng-model` with a directive that creates an isolate scope on the same element [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896732/ngmodel-and-component-with-isolated-scope).

I suggest either not creating a new scope, or use `scope: true`.

Here is a simplified example that does not create a new scope:

```
<form name="form">
    <div ng-repeat="fruit in localFruits">
        {{fruit.name}}: 
        <input ng-model="fruit.cost" required-when-key="local" custom-required/> 
        bound value is: [{{fruit.cost}}]
    </div>
</form>
```

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.localFruits = [
      {name: 'banana'},
  ];
}
app.directive('customRequired', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
          console.log(attrs.requiredWhenKey);
      }
  };
});
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/qFdTJ/)</kbd>

Since the `required-when-key` attribute is just a string, you can get the value using `attrs.requiredWhenKey`.

If you don't create a new scope, you should also be able to remove most of the `$parent` lookups in your directive.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize the attribute was available to me that way. For others looking at this answer, here is my updated fiddle using Mark's suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/cmontgomery/mEvZd/