# ng-model vs other attribute for directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Does using `ng-model` hold any advantage over using any other attribute on the element to achieve a two way binding within a directive?

For example if I had an isolate scope and decided I just want to load the items via the directive attribute itself.

```
scope: {
  items: "=myDirective"
}

<div my-directive="items"></div>
```

vs

```
<div my-directive ng-model="items"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the view in your directive can change the model (through inputs, selects, etc.), then you'll want to use `ng-model` so that you can you can use the [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) to update the model from the view. If you're always changing the model from controllers, then there's no need to use `ng-model`, as angular will update your view for you. The key is just if the view itself ever changes the model.

Comment: I'll add that if you want to use ngModelController in your directive, don't use an isolate scope.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896732/ngmodel-and-component-with-isolated-scope

Comment: That's rather interesting, @MarkRajcok because I am using directives with isolate scopes.