# Cannot figure out how to create a directive with $parsers and $formatters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a directive that will allow a user to input a date in a wide variety of formats. When the underlying model changes (whether via direct user input, or programmatically), I would like it to display the date in a normalized format.

An example of this "in the wild" are the departure and return date inputs on [Google Flights](https://www.google.com/flights).

Here's my code (which does not work at all).

**VIEW**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="params.departDate" 
  date-input display-format="{Weekday} {d} {Month}, {yyyy}">
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.params = {
      departDate: new Date()
  };
  $scope.isDate = function() {
      return $scope.params.departDate instanceof Date;
  }
});
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
app.directive("dateInput", function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            displayFormat: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (viewVal) {
                if (viewVal) {
                    // Using sugar.js for date parsing
                    var parsedValue = Date.create(viewVal);
                    if (parsedValue.isValid()) {
                        ngModel.$setValidity("date", true);
                        return parsedValue;
                    }
                }
                ngModel.$setValidity("date", false);
                return viewVal;
            });

            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (modelVal) {
                if (modelVal){
                    // Using sugar.js for date formatting
                    var date = Date.create(modelVal);
                    if (date.isValid()) {
                        return date.format(scope.displayFormat || '{Weekday} {d} {Month}, {yyyy}')
                    }
                }
                return modelVal;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

This doesn't even come close to working as I would expect. What am I doing wrong?

**Here's a PLUNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/583yOD6aRhRD8Y2bA5gU?p=preview**

Comment: ng-model and isolate scopes don't mix well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896732/ngmodel-and-component-with-isolated-scope  I suggest not creating any scope in your directive, and access the display-format attribute using attrs: `var displayFormat = attrs.displayFormat`.

Comment: Thank you 1000 times! You just saved me $500 for a new monitor which I was about to smash with a brick out of frustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, ng-model and isolate scopes don't mix well, see [Can I use ng-model with isolated scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896732/ngmodel-and-component-with-isolated-scope).

I suggest not creating any scope in your directive, and access the display-format attribute using attrs:

```
var displayFormat = attrs.displayFormat;
```

Answer (score 1):

I also prefer isolated scope with reusable directives, in that case ng-model has to be given proper path to parent scope: ng-model="$parent.params.departDate"

updated plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/DuR6Om2kyzWD67hYExSh?p=preview