# Angular custom validator directive breaking other directives

Tags: validation, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a directive for input fields which validates using a custom function passed from the outer scope, for example:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" custom-validator="checkValidity"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.checkValidity = function(value){
    return $scope.invalidWords.indexOf(value) === -1;
}
```

I've created a detailed plunker for this: http://plnkr.co/edit/H5A5O3?p=preview

Validation works, but it seems to broke things up with the default directives, in this case ng-disabled doesn't work and I can't access the variable  used in ng-model!

This is my directive:

```
app.directive('customValidator', function() {   
   return {
      require: "ngModel"
    , scope: { customValidator: '='}
    , link: function postLink(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
          var validator = function(value) {
            if(scope.customValidator && scope.customValidator(value)) {
              ctrl.$setValidity('custom-validator', true);
              return value;
            }
            ctrl.$setValidity('custom-validator', false);
            return undefined;
          }
          ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);
          ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validator);
        }      
   } 
});
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong, I really need help!

I should stay on Angular 1.0.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `ng-disabled` in not working on `inputB` is that you are creating a new scope through your directive:

```
scope: { customValidator: '=' }
```

To keep your model `inputB` in the same scope as `inputA` you can do something like this:

```
app.directive('customValidator', function() {
    return {
        require: "ngModel", 
        scope: false, 
        link: function postLink(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            var validator = function(value) {
                customValidator = scope[attrs["customValidator"]];  
                if(customValidator(value)) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('custom-validator', true);
                    return value;
                }
                ctrl.$setValidity('custom-validator', false);
                return undefined;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validator);
        }   
    }
});
```

Comment: It would work _but_ I couldn't pass a custom function. In my case I have to use 3 different functions for 3 form inputs. I've tried `transclude: true` but it seems not to fix this...

Comment: @destegabry Have a look at my updated directive that uses `attrs`.

Comment: +1, but I think using $parse is a little cleaner (see my answer).

Comment: @MarkRajcok I totally agree with you. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

ng-model and isolate scopes [don't mix well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896732/ngmodel-and-component-with-isolated-scope), so follow @Codezilla's advice and don't create a new scope.

However, I suggest using $parse, which allows us to clearly specify in the HTML that we are passing a function with a single (named) argument to the directive:

```
<input type="text" ... custom-validator="checkValidity(val)">
```

```
app.directive('customValidator', function($parse) {
    return {
        require: "ngModel", 
        //scope: false, 
        link: function postLink(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            var validationFn = $parse(attrs.customValidator);
            var validator = function(value) {
                if(validationFn(scope, {val: value})) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('custom-validator', true);
                    return value;
                }
                ctrl.$setValidity('custom-validator', false);
                return undefined;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validator);
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validator);
        }   
    }
});
```

<kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fg15aE?p=preview)</kbd>